# std::bad_alloc when adding a struct to std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, bad-alloc

this is probably something stupid, but i can't figure it out. I'm getting a `std::bad_alloc` exception in the following code snippet (which is a case statement in a switch):

```
case 0:
{
MyPrimitiveNode* node = new MyPrimitiveNode( 1, false );
TheStack.push_back( MyStackItem( node, TYPE_REF ) ); // bad_alloc here
break;
}
```

Where `TheStack` is of type `MyStack`, which is a `typedef std::vector<MyStackItem> MyStack;`

`MyStackItem` is a simple structure and looks like this:

```
struct MyStackItem {
    MyNode* value;
    uint8_t type;

    MyStackItem() {
        value = NULL;
        type = TYPE_UNDEF;
    }

    MyStackItem( MyNode* val, uint8_t t ) {
        value = val;
        type = t;
    }
};
```

As for `MyNode` nad `MyPrimitiveNode`, they come from another project (a static lib) and are defined as follows:

```
class MyNode
        {
        public:
            MyNode() {}
            virtual ~MyNode() {}
        };

class MyPrimitiveNode : public MyNode
    {
    public:
        bool bDeclaration;
        uint32_t u32ObjectIdx;

        MyPrimitiveNode() {
                        bDeclaration = false;
                        u32ObjectIdx = 0;
                    }
        MyPrimitiveNode( uint32_t id, bool declaration ) {
                        bDeclaration = declaration ;
                        u32ObjectIdx = id;
                    }
        ~MyPrimitiveNode() {}
    };
```

Hope this is all relevant info that is needed. I know that MyStackItem does only a shallow copy, this is how i want it. Dont worry about leaks, thats handled elsewhere.

Can someone tell my what is going on and how can i fix it? Thanks.

EDIT: posting the stack trace might help:

```
>   myProgram.exe!std::_Construct<MyStackItem,MyStackItem>(MyStackItem* _Ptr=0x003d3de8, const MyStackItem& _Val={...})  Line 52 + 0x33 bytes   C++
    myProgram.exe!std::allocator<MyStackItem>::construct(MyStackItem* _Ptr=0x003d3de8, const MyStackItem& _Val={...})  Line 155 + 0xd bytes C++
    myProgram.exe!std::_Uninit_fill_n<MyStackItem*,unsigned int,MyStackItem,std::allocator<MyStackItem> >(MyStackItem* _First=0x003d3de8, unsigned int _Count=0x00000001, const MyStackItem& _Val={...}, std::allocator<MyStackItem> & _Al={...}, std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag __formal={...}, std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag __formal={...})  Line 400 + 0x10 bytes  C++
    myProgram.exe!stdext::unchecked_uninitialized_fill_n<MyStackItem*,unsigned int,MyStackItem,std::allocator<MyStackItem> >(MyStackItem* _First=0x003d3de8, unsigned int _Count=0x00000001, const MyStackItem& _Val={...}, std::allocator<MyStackItem> & _Al={...})  Line 922 + 0x43 bytes C++
    myProgram.exe!std::vector<MyStackItem,std::allocator<MyStackItem> >::_Ufill(MyStackItem* _Ptr=0x003d3de8, unsigned int _Count=0x00000001, const MyStackItem& _Val={...})  Line 1252 + 0x18 bytes    C++
    myProgram.exe!std::vector<MyStackItem,std::allocator<MyStackItem> >::_Insert_n(std::_Vector_const_iterator<MyStackItem,std::allocator<MyStackItem> > _Where={value={...} type=??? }, unsigned int _Count=0x00000001, const MyStackItem& _Val={...})  Line 1184 + 0x14 bytes C++
    myProgram.exe!std::vector<MyStackItem,std::allocator<MyStackItem> >::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<MyStackItem,std::allocator<MyStackItem> > _Where={value={...} type=??? }, const MyStackItem& _Val={...})  Line 878  C++
    myProgram.exe!std::vector<MyStackItem,std::allocator<MyStackItem> >::push_back(const MyStackItem& _Val={...})  Line 823 + 0x58 bytes    C++
    myProgram.exe!MethodWhereExceptionOccurs
```

Comment: bad_alloc means can't allocate memory; so there's no contiguous space to allocate a MyStackItem object.

Comment: Can you show the code that created TheStack object. I am not seeing how this could fail and the asnwer could be TheStack object.

Comment: @iconIK: Well there is enough memory for sure, since the program takes up about 30kB in task manager when this exception is caught. @bcsanches: simply `MyStack TheStack;`. Nothing fancy.

Comment: How much memory the program takes beforehand isn't very relevant if the allocation attempt is for 9,000,000,000,000,000 bytes. Anyway, we need a testcase.

Comment: Added stack trace, which might help to spot the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That stack trace doesn't show anything that would lead me to believe that some part of the `push_back` is requesting a ton of memory.

Therefore, that pretty much leaves the option that your program has corrupted the heap somewhere ELSE and this allocation is the victim. Without more code and details all I can suggest is a memory checker like valgrind.

Does `MyStackItem` have a destruction you aren't showing us?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the answer. However, `MyStackItem` does not have any `user-defined` destructor.

Comment: Marked as accepted answer. The issue disappeared when i cleaned and rebuilt the solution. Very weird things started to happen after a while of debugging (like push_back inserting 4 elements with unitinialized (0xcd...) values.). Seems VS failed here.

Comment: @PeterK you comment saved alot of my time. "Clean"

Comment: @PeterK "Clean" saved me as well! thanks!